# Append a dynamic select box to a div after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.8

I am trying to append an accordion div after a button click. That works fine. But inside the appended div I have a select box , that has to be dynamically populated. After getting the Json results I tried to append the option values, but it failed. When I alert, I am getting the exact results.

Here is my controller

```
public function getTypes(){
    $types = AnsTypes::get();
    return response()->json($types);
}
```

My Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: site_base_url+ '/surveys/getquestiontypes',
    type: "get",
    contentType: "application/json",dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){ // What to do if we succeed
    if(data){
    $(".group:last").after('<div class="group">' +
    '<select class="custom-select" class="answer_datatype_id">' +
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
      '<option value="'+value.answer_datatype_id+'">' + value.type_name + '</option>'
      }) +
     '</select>'+
      '</div>');
});
```

My response payload is:

> JSON
>   0   {…}
>   answer_datatype_id  1
>   type_name   Text
>   1   {…}
>   answer_datatype_id  2
>   type_name   RadioButton
>   2   {…}
>   answer_datatype_id  3
>   type_name   CheckBox
>   3   {…}
>   answer_datatype_id  4
>   type_name   ListSingleSelection
>   4   {…}
>   answer_datatype_id  5
>   type_name   ListMultiSelection
>
> Response payload
>   [{"answer_datatype_id":1,"type_name":"Text"},{"answer_datatype_id":2,"type_name":"RadioButton"},{"answer_datatype_id":3,"type_name":"CheckBox"},{"answer_datatype_id":4,"type_name":"ListSingleSelection"},{"answer_datatype_id":5,"type_name":"ListMultiSelection"}]

My Result
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this look like your `$.each` not return the `<option>` to your DOM. You can try to add the `<option>` to a variable called `options` :

```
let options = "";
$.each(data, function(key, value){
      options +='<option value="'+value.answer_datatype_id+'">' + value.type_name + '</option>'
})
```

then you add your `options` to your DOM like this:

```
$(".group:last").after('<div class="group">' +
'<select class="custom-select" class="answer_datatype_id">' +
  options
   +
 '</select>'+
  '</div>');
```

this should work.
For the record I already tried this code and it works well, please let me know if you need something else.